# double sided mpage

Tags: pdf, svg

Hi I can easily use mpage to condense multiple single sided sheets on a single page.  However I am finding it tricky to do the same for double sided sheets. In this case I am printing badges. Say my input is

```
Badge01Front.pdf
Badge01Back.pdf
Badge02Front.pdf
Badge02Back.pdf
Badge03Front.pdf
...
```

How would I combine multiple badges onto a single sheet, so that if I cut up the sheet into badges, I get Badge01Front on one side of the first badge and Badge01Back on the other side? (and so on). FYI, I may be using SVGs instead of PDFs, but this shouldn't change much since they are easy to convert.

I have wrote [a bunch of scripts that basically do this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13OLQsBF0pccnoNuPb7JW52eXd9RRus0A/view), but they are complex and fragile. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a methodical approach: first assume the back filenames can be
derived simply from the front filenames. Then pad the number of front files
to be a multiple of the number per page; I've called this `nup`, from a
very old program of the same name. Using bash, create an indexed array
`files` of all the front filenames, padded with dummy place-holder files at
the end. Do a sheet at a time: extract `nup` filenames into a `sheet`
array. Add these to a `final` array which will have all the filenames in
the right order. Convert the sheet filenames to the back version filenames,
skipping over the dummy filenames.

Calculate the number of rows per sheet as `nup/width` where width is the
number of items across the page. For each row, calculate the start and end
index of the items in that row, and update those items in reverse order
from a copy of the sheet. Add the result to the `final` array.

This should make the following bash script clearer. I've assumed my front files are
called `f01.ps` and so on, and the back files `b01.ps`, with `dummy.ps`.
For clarity and brevity I have not double-quoted the variables, as I know my filenames.

```bash
nup=8
width=2
let numrows=nup/width
declare -a files final
files=(f*.ps)
dopad(){
    while numfiles=${#files[@]}
        let x=numfiles/nup*nup
        [ $x != $numfiles ]
    do  files+=(dummy.ps)
    done
}
doallsheets(){
    declare -a sheet
    let numsheets=numfiles/nup
    for sheetnum in $(seq $numsheets)
    do  let offset=(sheetnum-1)*nup
        for i in $(seq $nup)
        do  sheet+=(${files[$offset+$i-1]})
        done
        dosheet
        unset sheet
    done
}
dosheet(){
    final+=(${sheet[@]})
    convertnames
    swaprows
    final+=(${sheet[@]})
}
convertnames(){
    for i in $(seq $nup)
    do  if [ ${sheet[$i-1]} != dummy.ps ]
        then back=${sheet[$i-1]}
             sheet[$i-1]=${back/f/b}
        fi
    done 
}
swaprows(){
    declare -a sheetcopy=(${sheet[@]})
    for row in $(seq $numrows)
    do  let start=(row-1)*width
        let end=row*width-1
        swap
    done
}
swap(){
    for i in $(seq $width)
    do sheet[$start+$i-1]=${sheetcopy[$end-$i+1]}
    done
}
dopad
doallsheets
mpage -$nup -k -c -bA4 -l -a  -P- -L5 -W40 -H ${final[@]}  >out.ps
```

I tested this with some PostScript files generated by `enscript`:

```bash
create(){
    echo "$1" | enscript -fCourier30 -FCourierBold30 -p- | eps2eps - - >"${2?}"
}
startup(){
    for i in $(seq -f '%02.0f' 11)
    do  create "item $i front" f$i.ps
        create "item $i back" b$i.ps
    done
    create "dummy" dummy.ps
}
startup
```